# Apache mod-rewrite not accepting Double Inverted commas in query string

Tags: php, regex, linux, apache, mod-rewrite

MY rewrite code is not allowing double inverted commas in the query string of the URL, Following is the URL which is leading me to 404 page:
https://easypaper.cf/posts/Threats+of+using+%E2%80%9CShared+Wi-Fi%E2%80%9D.

The code properly handles and processes other URLs which do not contain "

Following is my Rewrite code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ([A-Za-z0-9-_"?]+)$    read.php?post=$1    [NC,L]
```

The server is using linux operating system. I don't know about the distributions and its version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ read.php?post=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It is always better to use a negated character class instead of matching everything till next `/` rather than including each and every character in character class.

Comment: Thanks. it worked.